# Version mismatch when migrating from spring-data-elasticsearch to spring-data-opensearch

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch, opensearch

First of all, we are using java version 17 and spring boot version 2.6.6.

We were currently using opensearch version 1.3 and the elasticSearch configuration was done for the client side and we had to switch to a new version for opensearch and we switched opensearch to version 2.11 and with the current configuration, there is this problem only in the save method, I get this error when productSearchRepository.saveAll(productSearchDataList) is done.

> org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Unable to parse response body for Response{requestLine=POST /_bulk?timeout=1m HTTP/1.1, host=https://*****.us-east-2.es.amazonaws.com:443, response=HTTP/1.1 200 OK};

This Problem is only related to the save method, because Get Methods like findById and findAll also work fine. Only the save method has this problem.

We wanted to change the client for openSearch and when I made the configuration below, I got the error with spring-data-elasticsearch 4.1.1 version.

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.support.HttpHeaders

Configuration

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.opensearch.client</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-opensearch</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

```
@Slf4j
@Getter
@Configuration
@EnableElasticsearchRepositories(basePackages = "com.asd.product")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.asd.product")
public class ElasticSearchConfig extends AbstractOpenSearchConfiguration {

    @Value("${elasticsearch.host}")
    private String host;

    @Value("${elasticsearch.username}")
    private String username;

    @Value("${elasticsearch.password}")
    private String password;

    @Value("${elasticsearch.socketTimeout}")
    private String socketTimeout;

    @Value("${elasticsearch.connectTimeout}")
    private String connectTimeout;

    @Value("${elasticsearch.searchSize}")
    private String searchSize;

    @Bean
    @Override
    public RestHighLevelClient opensearchClient() {
        final ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration =
                ClientConfiguration
                        .builder()
                        .connectedTo(new InetSocketAddress(host, 443))
                        .usingSsl()
                        .withSocketTimeout(Long.parseLong(socketTimeout))
                        .withConnectTimeout(Long.parseLong(connectTimeout))
                        .withBasicAuth(username, password)
                        .build();
        return RestClients.create(clientConfiguration).rest();
    }
}
```

To solve this problem, I had to install spring-data-elasticsearch 5.1.2 version and when I added this version, I got the following error

```
An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

    org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.config.ElasticsearchRepositoryConfigExtension.getModulePrefix(ElasticsearchRepositoryConfigExtension.java:64)

The following method did not exist:

    'java.lang.String org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.config.ElasticsearchRepositoryConfigExtension.getModuleIdentifier()'

The calling method's class, org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.config.ElasticsearchRepositoryConfigExtension, was loaded from the following location:

The called method's class hierarchy was loaded from the following locations:

org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.config.ElasticsearchRepositoryConfigExtension: 
    org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport: 

Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.config.ElasticsearchRepositoryConfigExtension
```

This error occurs with spring-data-commons 2.6.3 and data-elasticsearch 5.1.2

This is suggested as a solution, but if you haven't seen a solution, can you help?